# AJAX Frameworks for C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, frameworks

I am building a new app in .NET3.5. This app is heavily geared at retreival of information from backend web services, and so I would like to use AJAX to 'nicely' call my C# web services. What's the best way/framework/toolkit to use AJAX in VS2008?

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of the official library? Despite being in beta, it is robust and reliable.

ASP.net AJAX: http://www.asp.net/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asp.net/ajax/

http://www.asp.net/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/

you could use the .net ones.

I purchased telerik controls however and find them quite good.
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is the best solution. It is not specifically targeted to .NET, but it is easy to learn and very powerful. There are thousands plug-ins available. And VS2008 has intellisense support for it.